# Как обратиться к @keyframes rotate через JS?

Tags: javascript

```
@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Хочу поменять сторону в которую крутится элемент по клику.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Добавляем в *CSS* свойство, при котором будет срабатывать анимация
- При клике на кнопку, добавляем свойство, которое триггерит анимацию.

В данном случае при клике на `div` добавляется класс `.test`, а за счет того, что `div.test` запускает анимацию - все работает.

```js
var test = document.getElementById('test');

test.addEventListener('click', function(){
  this.className = this.className == 'test' ? 'test2' : 'test'; 
})
```

```css
@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate2 {
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  color: #FFF;
}

div.test {
  -webkit-animation: 1600ms rotate infinite alternate ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: 1600ms rotate infinite alternate ease-in-out;
  -ms-animation: 1600ms rotate infinite alternate ease-in-out;
  -o-animation: 1600ms rotate infinite alternate ease-in-out;
  animation: 1600ms rotate infinite alternate ease-in-out;
}
div.test2 {
  -webkit-animation: 1600ms rotate2 infinite alternate ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: 1600ms rotate2 infinite alternate ease-in-out;
  -ms-animation: 1600ms rotate2 infinite alternate ease-in-out;
  -o-animation: 1600ms rotate2 infinite alternate ease-in-out;
  animation: 1600ms rotate2 infinite alternate ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">Loading...</div>
```

---

Тоже самое, но более наглядно (через поворот по Z)

```js
var test = document.getElementById('test');

test.addEventListener('click', function(){
  this.className = this.className == 'test' ? 'test2' : 'test'; 
})
```

```css
@keyframes rotate {
   from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}



@keyframes rotate2 {
   from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  color: #FFF;
}

div.test {
  -webkit-animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
  animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
}
div.test2 {
   -webkit-animation: rotate2 2s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: rotate2 2s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: rotate2 2s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: rotate2 2s linear infinite;
  animation: rotate2 2s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="test" class="test">Loading...</div>
```

---

Однако в таком подходе есть очевидный изъян - анимация начинает "реверсировать" не с того места, где закончилась предыдущая, а с того, как указано в *CSS*

Чтобы начинать движение с того места, где закончилась предыдущая при клике - надо делать всё через скрипт.

Comment: А как сделать так, что б по клику меняло направление ?

Comment: @YURII, в оси Y реально будет заметно изменение направления вращения?

Comment: да, хочу -360 менять напросто 360

Comment: Поправил сниппет, при повторном клике анимация сменится на "обратную"

Comment: @br3t вандал!))

Comment: @YURII смотри измененный код.... аналогия из этого сырого демо должны быть ясна

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , я не специально, оно само...