# Как поменять rotate на rotate2 через JS?

Tags: javascript, css3, css-animation

```
.side {
  margin: 150px auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  animation: rotate 10s infinite linear;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate2 {
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: можно убрать класс через JS и поставить новый, с правильной анимацией и стилями в целом.

Comment: также, как вариант `object.style.animation = "rotate2 10s infinite linear";` Но, с заменой класса, думаю действительно лучше.

Comment: @NeedHate, вариант со сменой класса был тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/674036/221753 , но он, видимо, не подошел

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через `Element.style.animationName`.

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('.side').style.animationName = "rotate2";
}
```

```css
.side {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  animation: rotate 10s infinite linear;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate2 {
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="side"></div>

<button>change animation</button>
```